# Вопрос Laravel по отношениям

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Есть 3 модели `Region`, `Branch`, `User` и одна сводная таблица `user_branches` в ней поля `user_id` и `branch_id`

У региона есть филиалы там отношения

```
public function branches(){
    return $this->hasMany(Branch::class);
}
```

У филиала есть отношение

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_branches');
}
```

Как мне вернуть все регионы которые есть в базе с филиалами, но только те филиалы которые доступны залогиненному юзеру

Получаю так все регионы и филиалы в них `Region::with('branches')->get();`, вот тут получается нужно отсортировать только те филиалы которые доступны юзеру

Comment: Лара не умеет соединять 3 и более модели. Но есть пакет [staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep](https://packagist.org/packages/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep). Я его использую.

Comment: `Region::with('branches')->whereHas('branches', fn($builder) => $builder->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get()` как то так

Comment: Или сделайте отношение ко многим через

Comment: fn($builder) это ошибка ?

Comment: @Walfter не пойму что за fn ? исправьте пожалуйста

Comment: fn это [стрелочная функция](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.arrow.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать query builder внутри with. В данном случае нужна комбинация `with()` + `whereHas()`.

Получить все регионы с отфильтрованными филиалами:

```
$regions = Region
    ::with([
        'branches' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', auth()->id());
            });
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

Получить только те регионы, в которых есть отфильтрованные филиалы, с отфильтрованными филиалами:

```
$regions = Region
    ::with([
        'branches' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', auth()->id());
            });
        }
    ])
    ->whereHas('branches', function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', auth()->id());
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

Если база данных пожалуется на колонку `id`, тогда надо заменить `id` на `users.id`:

```
$query->where('users.id', auth()->id());
```